# Why do the links to chat rooms show up randomly?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, chat

I'm not sure when it happened, but at some point the links on the sidebar to The Comms Room and Vote to Close went away.  I wondered about their disappearance, but didn't bother to post a question here.

Today I noticed that *sometimes* on *some* questions, the links show up.  I can't quite see a pattern, but it looks like questions that are posted in a chat room have the links on them?

In any case, would it be possible to get the links back - permanently?

Comment: I [noticed the same thing today](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1658/1547), but with the *main page* of EL&U. @Jeff's explanation doesn't seem to apply to that. Any ideas?

Comment: AdBlock Plus nails them in FF for me... Got ad blocking software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we suppress house ad sidebar elements until there are enough answers that the "Related Questions" -- which are rather important -- are not pushed down too far.

edit: one caveat. on meta we indeed show the chat ad at all times in the sidebar.

Comment: So the chat bar is an ad sidebar element?